# Running xUnit test under NCrunch --- System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Void Xunit.Assert.Null(...)

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, xunit.net, missingmethodexception, ncrunch

I'm trying to get NCrunch up and running with an existing solution in VS 2012. However, the unit tests won't run when initiated via NCrunch.

I get a Method not found: 'Void Xunit.Assert.Null(..) error when attempting to run unit tests under NCrunch.

The test runs when running using xUnit "Run Unit Tests" context menu, or the built-in "Run Tests" from within the IDE.

I've tried cleaning and re-compiling, both in Debug and Release Modes. I've tried debugging the test under NCrunch (it didn't work). I've also checked the GAC for an instance of the xUnit assembly, and it isn't there.

Versions:

- NCrunch v2.4.0.2
- XUnit Runner for VS 2012/2013 v0.99.3
- Visual Studio 2012
- Code is in C#

Here is the output from the NCrunch Tests window:

```
*** ConsoleOutput ***

Unable to read configuration section common/logging.  Using no-op implemenation.

*** Failures ***

Exception
System.MissingMethodException: System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Void Xunit.Assert.Null(System.Object, System.String)'.
   at XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXXTest.Test_Yada()
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this problem?